# Append text to a TextView datatype

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview

I'm a beginner android/java programmer and my background is primarily in C++ and C#. In C# if I have a string variable called myWord and it has a value of "Hello" I can append additional information by using the + operator.

I tried this method a few times in java and apparently I can't use this tatic because the TextView datatype is void. Android studio gives me the following error: Operator '+' cannot be applied to 'void', 'java.lang.String'

```
/*C # */
public string bob ()
{
return "Bob!";
}

string myWord = "Hello ";
myWord = myWord + "Bob!"; //myWord is now equal to "Hello Bob!"

OR 

myWord = "Hello " + bob(); //myWord is now equal to "Hello Bob!"


*/ JAVA */
TextView displayTextView = null;
displayTextView.setText("Hello");
```

I'd like to find a way to append additional text to the original value of "Hello" so the value of displayTextView will be "Hello Bob!"

Any ideas?

Edit: I'm currently using a capital "S" and my app can successfully access and retrieve information from my class. The app would FC whenver I tried to append text to to the TextView data type.

Thank you for the feedback everyone.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can call `append()` on a TextView object.

In your case it would be: `displayTextView.append("Bob!");`

Answer (score 12):

If you are using TextView, use [append](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#append(java.lang.CharSequence)). For example:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText);
textView.setText("Hello");
textView.append(" Bob!");
```

Answer (score 3):

Why nobody suggested `getText()` method ?

```
TextView displayTextView = null;
displayTextView.setText("text1");
displayTextView.setText(displayTextView.getText() + "text2");//poor and weak
```

or better for longer strings:

```
SpannableString ss =new SpannableString();
ss.append("text1").append("text2");
displayTextView.setText(ss);
```

Comment: because textview has append method, that's why

Answer (score 1):

First letter of String is not small letter. To take a String variable in java you have to write String var;

So, for android use following code:

```
TextView displayTextView = null;
TextView displayTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText);
String myWord = "Your";
displayTextView.setText("Hello " + myword);
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is on your declaration of the String instance in both the method and the variable.

It requires a "S" not a lower case s.

Also the "+" sign does work, it is just your String declaration as pointed out.

[image: Here is how it looks]

All the best :)