# how to append strings to textview

Tags: java, android, textview

What is the best way to add strings to a textview in a for loop? I am using the method "setText and it's overwriting the previous string rather than adding to.
Here is my code below:

```
 List<PlaceLikelihood> placeLikelihoodList = placesResult.getPlaceLikelihoods();
     int hospitalType = Place.TYPE_HOSPITAL;

     if (placeLikelihoodList != null) {
         for (int i = 0; i <placeLikelihoodList.size(); i++){
         PlaceLikelihood p = placeLikelihoodList.get(i);
         List<Integer> types = p.getPlace().getPlaceTypes();
     }

     if (types.get(0).equals(hospitalType)) {
         groceryStoreTextView.setText(p.getPlace().getName().toString());
     }
```

Comment: `TextView` has an `append()` method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append text to a TextView datatype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636230/append-text-to-a-textview-datatype)

Comment: Thank you! @MikeM.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `TextView.append()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this:

Edit:-

```
groceryStoreTextView.setText(groceryStoreTextView.getText().toString() + p.getPlace().getName().toString());
```